# Predicting volcanic eruptions by experimentally proven volatile outgassing observations

Tags: volcanology, geochemistry, volcanoes, volcanic-hazard

In the abstract for the article [Forecasting Etna eruptions by real-time observation of volcanic gas composition](http://geology.gsapubs.org/content/35/12/1115.abstract) (Aiuppa et al. 2007), the authors assert that real time monitoring of volcanic volatiles, such as $\ce{H2O}$, $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{SO2}$ and ratios thereof, could be a potential tool for volcanic eruption prediction, as exemplified by their modelling of Mt. Etna volcanic volatile geochemistry.

However, at the time of the article, according to the authors,

> It is generally accepted, **but not experimentally proven**, that a quantitative prediction of volcanic eruptions is possible from the evaluation of volcanic gas data.

**Has there been experimental proof of the effectiveness of real time monitoring of volcanic volatiles in volcanic eruption prediction?**